# JavaScript: Replace list from array by clicking next

Tags: javascript, html

How can I replace the whole list without adding new li's to the list?

I think I should "reboot" it somehow, but I'm not sure how.
I could just do it by filling empty li's in the HTML file, but then I'll have a problem when there are more or less items.

```js
let objects = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "broom",
    "places": ["kitchen", "shop", "pharmacy"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "wheels",
    "places": ["park", "pool", "square"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "wood",
    "places": ["church", "garage", "bathroom"]
  }
];

const nameObject = document.getElementById('objectName');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('objectNext');
let objectIndex = 0;

nextBtn.onclick = function () {
  objectIndex === objects.length - 1 ?
    objectIndex = 0 :
    objectIndex ++;
  nameObject.innerHTML = objects[objectIndex].name;
  objects[objectIndex].places.forEach(place => {
    createPlaceListItem(place);
  });
};

const createPlaceListItem = place => {
  const $item = document.createElement(`li`);
  $item.classList.add(`objectListItem`);
  $item.innerHTML = place;
  document.getElementById(`placeList`).appendChild($item);
};

nameObject.innerHTML = objects[objectIndex].name;
objects[objectIndex].places.forEach(place => {
  createPlaceListItem(place);
});
```

```html
<h4 id="objectName" class="objectName"></h4>
<ul class="objectList" id="placeList">
</ul>

<button class="objectNext" id="objectNext">next</button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `innerHTML` to clean the list is effective, using a proper [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) is not only arguably more idiomatic but also faster (although the performance will not matter for such small lists). It can be just:

```
while (list.firstChild) list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
```

Here is your code with that line:

```js
let objects = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "broom",
    "places": ["kitchen", "shop", "pharmacy"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "wheels",
    "places": ["park", "pool", "square"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "wood",
    "places": ["church", "garage", "bathroom"]
  }
];

const nameObject = document.getElementById('objectName');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('objectNext');
const list = document.getElementById(`placeList`);
let objectIndex = 0;

nextBtn.onclick = function() {
  objectIndex === objects.length - 1 ?
    objectIndex = 0 :
    objectIndex++;
  nameObject.innerHTML = objects[objectIndex].name;
  while (list.firstChild) list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  objects[objectIndex].places.forEach(place => {
    createPlaceListItem(place);
  });
};

const createPlaceListItem = place => {
  const $item = document.createElement(`li`);
  $item.classList.add(`objectListItem`);
  $item.innerHTML = place;
  list.appendChild($item);
};

nameObject.innerHTML = objects[objectIndex].name;
objects[objectIndex].places.forEach(place => {
  createPlaceListItem(place);
});
```

```html
<h4 id="objectName" class="objectName"></h4>
<ul class="objectList" id="placeList">
</ul>

<button class="objectNext" id="objectNext">next</button>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is a `removeChild` faster than `.innerHTML` if you were to have a really long list of items? Wouldn't it make sense to just delete the entire `innerHTML` instead of removing each child one by one?

Comment: @DaMahdi03 I understand that it's counterintuitive, but see it by yourself: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/34/0/innerhtml-vs-removechild

Comment: Thanks for the info! This does indeed seem to be the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `innerHTML` to clean up the list before you append your new items

In your `onclick` you can reset your list

```js
nextBtn.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById(`placeList`).innerHTML = ""; //Clear the list before you append new values to it
  objectIndex === objects.length - 1 ?
    objectIndex = 0 :
    objectIndex ++;
  nameObject.innerHTML = objects[objectIndex].name;
  objects[objectIndex].places.forEach(place => {
    createPlaceListItem(place);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to 'reboot' just add this to the start of the onClick function

```
document.getElementById(`placeList`).innerHTML = '';
```